# Unable to renew certificate in certmgr.msc in windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, certificate, ad-certificate-services

I am trying to renew a certificate using CertManager on Windows 2003 Server.  (I have also used the certificate plug-in in MMC but its the same thing.)  I am logged in with the Administrator account.

When I select any of my Personal certificates and go to the All-Tasks menu I only see Open and Export.  I do not see the "Renew Certificate with New Key" or "Renew this certificate with the same key" options.

How do I get those options to show up?  Is there some security policy or service that I need to run?

Comment: I was able to find the Request/Renew certificate options by clicking on the Personal folder and doing Find Certificates.  When I right click on the Expiring Certificate and select Renew I get the following error:  The wizard cannot be started because it failed to contact the Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some certification.

- Is this an enterprise or standalone CA?
- What type of certificate are you using?

Did you try to use the web interface? Perhaps that would do it for you: http://ServerName/certsrv

You may also take a look here for a reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775718(WS.10).aspx

Comment: I believe it is an Enterprise CA.